# Json deserializer gets 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, httprequest

I am trying to make CRUD functionality for the table **Recipe**. Everything works fine in the API, however, I am stuck at the Update part inside the MVC. Basically, when trying to access the view meant for updating, all of the fields should be already filled, compared to when I am creating a recipe from scratch.

[image]

```
    public ActionResult CreateOrEdit(int id = 0)
    {
        if (id==0)
            return View(new Recipe());
        else
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariablesUpdate.clientUp.GetAsync(id.ToString()).Result;
            var temp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return View(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(response.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

The code inside the `else{}`is meant to fill all the values after reading the content. Unfortunately, on line

> ```
> return View(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(response.ToString()));
> ```

I am getting the following error

> 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '',
>   line 0, position 0.'

The temp variable's content looks like this:

```
"[{\"id\":5002,\"name\":\"Test Recipe\",\"recipeLink\":\"testlink\",\"category1Id\":7757,\"category2Id\":7758,\"category3Id\":7759,\"category4Id\":7760,\"recipeById\":1,\"totalTime\":30,\"totalTimeUnitId\":1,\"activeTime\":20,\"activeTimeUnitId\":1,\"instructions\":\"Test Instructions\",\"sourceKey\":\"Test SK\",\"recipeBy\":\"TestPerson\",\"insertedAtUtc\":\"2019-09-04T12:18:48.0466667\",\"isVerified\":1,\"numPersons\":5}]"
```

I assume the root of this problem is that my `response` variable has these backslashes, hence the unexpected character encounter. How can I get rid of this?

**EDIT**

`.Replace(@"\", " ")` doesn't work, so I assume that the backslash might not actually be the issue?

Comment: What is the value of `response.ToString()` (check in the `Immediate Window`)?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but: `"StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0\r\n  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n  Date: Mon, 09 Sep 2019 09:10:09 GMT\r\n  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n}"`

Comment: Does that look like JSON to you (the string that you just shared with me)?

Comment: Hint - use `temp` rather than `response.ToString()`.

Comment: Not at all. response.Content does. The value shown for response.ToString() inside the Immediate Window is the one I've copy pasted above.

Comment: Oh, I see your point now...

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deserializing `response.ToString()`, but you should be deserializing `temp`:

```
var recipes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(temp);
return View(recipes);
```

Sidenotes: you should make your method async, to avoid deadlocks, and dispose your response:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateOrEdit(int id = 0)
{
    if (id==0)
    {
        return View(new Recipe());
    }

    using (var response = await GlobalVariablesUpdate.clientUp.GetAsync(id.ToString())
    {
        var temp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var recipes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>(temp);
        return View(recipes);
    }
}
```

Comment: After writing my code like this: `return View(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Recipe>(temp));`, I am getting the following error: `: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'UI.Models.Recipe' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type the...`. Any idea why that happens? I had to tweak my code a little bit because I was getting some ViewDictionary error so I removed the List<>

Comment: @Questieme You are doing `DeserializeObject<Recipe>`, you should do `DeserializeObject<IList<Recipe>>` as written in both the question and the answer.